# Remove column mean from nonzero entries of a column

Tags: matlab, mean

Given an sparse matrix **A** in MATLAB and the mean for the nonzero elements in its columns **m**, is there anyway to subtract the nonzero elements in each column from the mean of each column and avoid looping over columns?

I am looking for efficient solutions. Using 'bsxfun' could be one solution if it is possible to use.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the second output of [`find`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to get the column indices; use those to index into `m` to do the subtraction; and put the results back into `A` using [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/):

```
A = sparse([0 0 0 0; 1 0 3 2; 2 1 0 5]); %// example data
m = [1.5 1 3 3.5]; %// vector of mean of nonzero elements of each column
m = m(:);
[~, jj, vv] = find(A);
A(logical(A)) = vv - m(jj);
```

Original `A`:

```
>> full(A)
ans =
     0     0     0     0
     1     0     3     2
     2     1     0     5
```

Final `A`:

```
>> full(A)
ans =
         0         0         0         0
   -0.5000         0         0   -1.5000
    0.5000         0         0    1.5000
```

Comment: Awesome ! Thanks Luis

Comment: @YAS Welcome! Glad that was what you wanted

Comment: BTW, you could also use `bsxfun(@minus, A, m).*logical(A)`, but the intermediate result of `bsxfun` won't be sparse, so you may perhaps run into memory problems

Comment: Thanks, definitely that is true.